# dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) block doesn't execute

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, dispatch-async

I have a block to download an convert an image to UIImage. this is my code

```
-(UIImage *)GetProfileImage
{
NSString *strimgBaseUrl=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"BaseImageURL"];
NSString *strFilePath=[dm.dictUserProfile valueForKey:@"ImagePath"];
NSString *strImgURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",strimgBaseUrl,strFilePath];
__block UIImage *imgProf=nil;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strImgURL];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        imgProf= image;
        if(image!=nil){
            imgProf=image;

        }


    });
});



  return imgProf;
}
```

But this block is never execute.It goes to `return` `__block UIImage *imgProf=nil;` Why is that? Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason for using GCD here?

Comment: If you simply want to get image from a URL, you can use this answer that I wrote a while ago. And yup it works with a block. Yup it works asynchronously. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728793/instagram-photo-to-uiimageview/33728839#33728839

Comment: What is the value of `strImgURL`?  Cocoa classes which load from URL only work with a local (file://) URLs.

Comment: The block is executing. But it is executing in the background long after the call to `return imgProf;` is made.

Comment: strImgURL is a http:// url

Comment: I have already set allow arbitrary load yes, data is loading properly. Only images can't get in that way

Comment: rmaddy has already pointed out the issue in your code. it is returning a nil image before the call ever gets back.

Answer (score 1):

Code is working ok. This is the purpose of `dispatch_async`.

Form the documentation

> @function dispatch_async
>
> Calls to dispatch_async() always return immediately after the block has   been submitted, and never wait for the block to be
>   invoked.

This is the opposite of `dispatch_sync`.

You could change the `GetProfileImage` like this

```
- (void)setProfileImageForImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView {
    NSString *strimgBaseUrl=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"BaseImageURL"];
    NSString *strFilePath=[dm.dictUserProfile valueForKey:@"ImagePath"];
    NSString *strImgURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",strimgBaseUrl,strFilePath];
    __block UIImage *imgProf=nil;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strImgURL];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            imgProf= image;
            if(image!=nil){
                // imgProf=image;
                imageView.image = image;
            }


        });
    });
}
```

Comment: The initial premise is to get the profile picture. your method is void & not returning  a UIImage. You are assuming that OP does not want to perform any action with the image once he is done fetching it other than setting it to an image view.

Answer (score 0):

Use a completion block instead, rather than returning from function:

```
-(void)GetProfileImageWithCompletion:(void (^)(UIImage *profileImage))completionHandler
{
NSString *strimgBaseUrl=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"BaseImageURL"];
NSString *strFilePath=[dm.dictUserProfile valueForKey:@"ImagePath"];
NSString *strImgURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",strimgBaseUrl,strFilePath];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strImgURL];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if(image!=nil && completionHandler){
            completionHandler(image);
        }
    });
});
}
```

And use like this:

```
[self GetProfileImageWithCompletion:^(UIImage *profileImage)
   {
      //if image exists assign to image view
   }
];
```